# Largest possible subset primes

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, asymptotics

Let $q$ be a Sophie Germain prime number, i.e. $2q+1=p$ is prime. Consider the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,p-1\}$. Then what is the maximum size of a subset of this set, such that the subset contains no two elements, $a,b$, such that:

1. $b\equiv \{a,2a,3a,4a,5a\}\pmod {p-1}$
2. $a\equiv \{b,2b,3b,4b,5b\}\pmod {p-1}$.

For example, for $q=11$ we have $p=23$, and we can pick the 5 element subset $\{2,5,11,16,21\}\subset \{1,2,3,4,\ldots,22\}$ that satisfies the property.

In general, how big can we make "5"?

I haven't been able to find any UPPER bounds, but I know from experimenting a lot that it cannot be a linear (or higher) function of $p$. So it has to be like $\sqrt{2p}$ or something.

EDIT: I added the word "upper" before "bound", as I am looking mainly for upper bounds

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Changed

Comment: 5 has two roles: The forbidden values of $b/a$ are $1..5=m$; and the size of the set is $5=n$.  Do you want $n=m$?

Comment: @Michael: No, sorry, that was a bad example. 5 is constant and stays "5" for large subsets.

Answer (score 1):

Every new number rules out the nine numbers $a,2a,3a,4a,5a,a/2,a/3,a/4,a/5$.  So there should be at least $\lfloor (p+8)/9\rfloor$ numbers in the set.  Perhaps there is overlap, and you can find more.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I am looking for an upper bound, is it possible? In other words, "at most" not "at least". Thank you

Comment: The upper bound is at least equal to the lower bound $p/9$, which is linear in $p$.  Another upper bound is $p$ :)

Comment: Thanks. I think the answer is at most $1+\sqrt{2p}$ but haven't been able to prove it. Will you attempt it if I give you the full problem? I will make a new topic if you want to post an answer

Comment: A new question is a good idea if you give the full problem.  I will look at it if I am still around here.  You can reach my answer, which should be $(p-1)/9$, by simply including a number in the set if it doesn't clash with earlier numbers.  It is more than your number if $p>180$.

Comment: Let $p$ be a prime number such that $(p-1)/2$ is also prime, and let $a,b,c$ be integers not divisible by $p$. Prove that there are at most $1+\sqrt{2p}$ positive integers $n<p$ such that $p$ divides $a^n+b^n+c^n$.